# switch built targets in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, clion

I was a CLION user for long, and until recently I switched to visual studio 2017 since CLION uses too much memory.

In CLION, basically I can cmake the whole project with the top-level cmake file and generates multiple targets to select from a drop-down button.

I did the same in visual studio except in visual studio I need to run the cmake first to generate a .sln file and open it in visual studio.

After open this, I can see different class instances(my targets) in the solution explorer, but I do not know where to specify which target to run. Each of my target has its own main function. Also, I have integrates all my targets into a top level object called BUILD_ALL. I can build this build_all which builds all of my individual target. But still i dont know how to run each one.

I tried by using the right-click and start a new instance, but it rebuilds the target everytime which is not wanted. In Clion, this is not a problem.

Could someone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `Set as Startup Project` option.  This will make it so the build and debug shortcuts target the selected project.

Right click on the project in the solution explorer and choose `Set as Startup Project`
[image]

Another option is to just build and or debug the project directly from the right click context menu.
[image]

Depending on how much you work with CMake and Visual Studio you may want to look into [VS_STARTUP_PROJECT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VS_STARTUP_PROJECT.html?highlight=vs_#prop_dir:VS_STARTUP_PROJECT)